# How to search in bootstrap typehead after three characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using bootstrap-typehead.js, it will work like auto complete, in bootstrap-typehead it will search the result after one word, but I want to search it after three words.

This is my html code:

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[&quot;Ahmedabad&quot;,&quot;Akola&quot;,&quot;Asansol&quot;,&quot;Aurangabad&quot;,&quot;Bangaluru&quot;,&quot;Baroda&quot;,&quot;Belgaon&quot;,&quot;Berhumpur&quot;,&quot;Calicut&quot;,&quot;Chennai&quot;,&quot;Chapra&quot;,&quot;Cherapunji&quot;]">
```

I want to search these words after three words.

Comment: Do you want it to show after 3 characters or 3 words? Your description and title don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option `minLength` (look at the doc : http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) :

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-min-length=3 .../>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7JsTp/

Comment: it work on fiddle but didn't work in my file :-) any other solution?

Comment: @usii : strange... Have you got the same version of bootstrap-typehead as in my example (v2.2.2)? Can you reproduce your behaviour in another fiddle?

Comment: i m using v2.0.1, is there any option in this version?